# How to skip to the end of a loop from a within a yield statememt

Tags: ruby, loops, iteration, block, yield

So I have a recursive call that looks something like this:

```
def foo list, &block
   list.each do |a|
      newlist = a.bar
      yield a
      foo newlist, &block
   end
end
```

And I am trying to pass into the code block to not recur if, say, a == 0.

```
foo list do |a|
   next if a == 0
end
```

However, this seems to not work. So I tried passing in an additional boolean into the block, but it apparently makes a copy of the boolean instead of an alias (I had thought even primitive types in ruby were aliased since everything is an object).

So this didn't work either:

```
def foo list, &block
   list.each do |a|
      newlist = a.bar
      continue = true
      yield a, continue
      foo newlist, &block if continue
   end
end

foo list do |a, c|
   c = false if a == 0
end
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm attempting here?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It would be helpful to included a simple example, including the expected or desired return value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `break` instead of `next` inside the block. Callin break shoul terminate both block and method block was called from(foo in your example). Not sure if that's what you are looking for though

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed by just making a Bool_Wrapper class that just contains a boolean and has attr_accessor for the boolean. But hopefully someone knows a better way to get around this!

```
class Boolean_Holder
   def initialize bool
      @bool = bool
   end
   attr_accessor :bool
end

def foo list, &block
   list.each do |a|
      newlist = a.bar
      continue = Boolean_Holder true
      yield a, continue
      foo newlist, &block if continue.bool
   end
end

foo list do |a, c|
   c.bool = false if a == 0
end
```